# C# Replace desktop background in real-time

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, desktop

I need to change the desktop image in windows 7 in real time, or replace the background with an control for building some desktop effects in C# WinForms, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net

Comment: I need to do this in real-time, like Android Live Wallpaper

Comment: Please check the following urls .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886786/change-windows-wallpaper-using-net-4-0

Comment: You could setup a [Windows RSS-fed dynamic theme](http://www.wincom7.com/blog/how-to-set-up-rss-themes-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Does "in real time" mean that the desktop changes as soon as you call your function?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows 7 DreamScene Activator](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewindowsclub.com%2Fwindows-7-dreamscene-activator-released&ei=myxTULrVDMaA4gTCzoHQBg&usg=AFQjCNEJ2CmFIV1U9jp5P1RrAiM034LHYA&sig2=gGDtyirCmCXRRgCYPE_jtQ) allows the usage of videos as backgrounds (it's pretty CPU-intensive though, handle with care).

I use it on my nerding rig, it's quite straightforward, only caveat is the resolution of videos must be rather low or they *will* stutter.